# how to configure terminal in a text boot?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bashrc, xterm, text-mode

I use tmux in xterm and gnome-terminal.Configuring gnome-terminal's background and foreground is not an issue as it can be easily done through gui itself.Few things to mention:

1. I can configure xterm like the foreground color and background color to green and black respectively using `~/.Xresources` file.here a screenshot of xterm:

[image]

2. I have a `~/.tmux.conf` file for tmux configuration.

I have set up my system to boot up in text mode , it asks login name and password. After logging in it shows prompt but no green foreground just the primitive white and black foreground and background ,though it opens tmux (i think that's because of the code I put for tmux in bashrc) automatically.

First of all I thought xterm opens up after login so i configured it using `.Xresources` file thinking it would configure that *after text boot terminal* but it did nothing,i.e I get white and black foreground and background. which terminal do i have to configure for this to work? I mean xterm, uxterm , lxterm or gnome-terminal ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the linux console which opens after booting in CLI mode gets its parameters and characteristics directly from the `.bashrc` file, so, I did a little tweak to my bash file to get the above layout. Here is what I did:

```
test -z "$TMUX" && (tmux new-session -d && tmux split-window -h && tmux split-window -v && tmux -2 attach-session -d)
```

The above command tests whether there is already a tmux session running or not (this test is necessary to avoid infinite splitting of window panes ), if not then create a new session and split windows in the above fashion.